# How to extend newcustomer.phtml in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, login, phtml

I want to change the default text

-- Creating an account has many benefits: check out faster, keep more than one address, track orders and more.

**So how would i extend the path vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/newcustomer.phtml.**

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only wants to modify the text i suggest to use translations: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

translations are not used only for translating to another language, but also to modify the text in a given language.

you can use/create a translation file in a custom module, for example:

```
app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/i18n/en_US.csv
```

or the translation file from your theme:

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/i18n/en_US.csv
```

You can find the translation key inside of `__(..)` in your template, which in your case is `Creating an account has many benefits: check out faster, keep more than one address, track orders and more.`. Adding the following line to a translation file, will modify the output

`"Creating an account has many benefits: check out faster, keep more than one address, track orders and more.","New label to create an account"`

Still if you need to modify the template, the best is to override it into a child template: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html

for example to override

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/newcustomer.phtml
```

copy it into

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Customer/templates/newcustomer.phtml
```

for both approaches you need to clear the cache to see the result.

Comment: @Eefan Thanks for the help i have used child theme approach and it works.